# Efficient use of trim and split for strings in Java

Tags: java, string, trim

The code I wrote here works, but I am pretty sure it is awful and not so efficient.
This function takes in input a list of strings which is splitted on comma and then each generated string is trimmed.

One example:

```
INPUT:    [[Cat, Dog, Snake]]
OUTPUT:   Cat Dog Snake
```

```
private List<String> splitListOfString(LinkedList<String> list)
{
    String mylist = list.toString();
    mylist = mylist.substring(2);
    mylist = mylist.substring(0, mylist.length() - 2);
    List<String> thelist = Arrays.asList(mylist.split(","));
    List<String> thelist2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (String string : thelist) {
        thelist2.add(string.trim());
    }
        return thelist2;
}
```

How would you improve this code?

Comment: *The code I wrote here works* -- Seems like you could use a CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Why is your input a *List* of strings and not just a single string? What exactly are the elements of this list?

Comment: Is your input `["[Cat", "Dog", "Snake]"]` *(size 3)* or `["[Cat, Dog, Snake]"]` *(size 1)*? My guess is the latter, but ... *why?*

Comment: Hint: A "list of strings" doesn't need to be `toString()`-d. You already have a list, so iterate over it, `trim()` the values,

Comment: Please check out [MCVE] (guidance on providing code in the post)  and provide input data for code in the post. As @cricket_007 commented `toString` call on list is very confusing - so hard to say why it is there and if removal will actually make code easier for data you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply `stream`ing and `collect`ing to a list?

```
return list.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
```